# C++ setprecision

Tags: c++

newbie learning C++ and not understanding the problem I have trying to use setprecision(2) says setprecision(2) is undefined. If anyone could help I'd be most grateful.

```
 #include <iostream>     
 #include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
double price,shipping;

cout<<"Enter total price of of the order: "<<endl;
cin>>price;

if(price > 75) 
    shipping = 0;
else if(price > 50) 
    shipping = 5;
else if(price > 25)
    shipping = 10;
else if(price > 0)
    shipping = 15;

cout<<"Total price of order including shipping is: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)
    <<price + shipping<<endl;





return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Learn to love the documentation. Open documentation for `std::setprecision` and read it. Also, stop `using namespace std;`.

Comment: ok thanks, stupidly enough as soon as I posted this I found the solution doh

Comment: Add `#include <iomanip>` to your includes

Comment: I have to use  using namespace std;  as I am using virtual studio.

Comment: He's suggesting you prefix your std namespace tokens with std:: rather than using "using namespace std." For example, std::cout, std::cin, etc. You can remove the "using namespace std" if you do that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

`setprecision()` function is included in the iomanip library. Simply include that library into your program. and you should be fine. :)

```
#include<iomanip>
```